# Asynchronous function call, with a method to check progress

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous

I need help to implement an asynchonous funtion call in C++. I am new to multithreading in C++.

There sould be two funtions: one to get the work started in another thread and one to check progress and if work has been finished.

I tried it with some code from different answers on this site, but it doesn't work.

```
int __stdcall Test::asyncStartWork()
{
    asyncReady = false;
    std::thread workThread = std::thread(&Test::doWork, this);
    return 0;
}

int __stdcall Test::asyncGetProgress()
{
    if (asyncReady = true)
    {
        workThread.join();
        return 100;
    }    
    else
    {
        return asyncProgress;
    }
}

int __stdcall Test::doWork()
{
   //do work and write progress to asyncProgress

   //at the end
   asyncReady = true
}
```

When calling asyncStartWork I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: [MCVE] is needed.  And a description of your actual problem.

Comment: Your thread object is local and will be destructed at the end of `asyncStartWork`. A quick fix would be `detach`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In method `Test::asyncStartWork()`, you are defining a local variable `workThread` which is hiding your class member.

So in `asyncGetProgress()`, when calling `workThread.join()`, you're calling it for a thread object which does not represent a thread (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread)).

This results in a `std::system_error` being thrown with error condition `no_such_process`. If your program is not catching exceptions, this would result in the process aborting.

Try removing the `std::thread` part in `asyncStartWork()`, e.g.

```
int __stdcall Test::asyncStartWork()
{
    asyncReady = false;
    workThread = std::thread(&Test::doWork, this);
    return 0;
}
```

Also, the `__stdcall`'s seem unnecessary.

Comment: thank you. what a stupid mistake. now it seems to work